# Replacing systemd-boot with GRUB2

Tags: systemd, boot, dual-boot, grub, uefi

i would like to install GRUB instead of syestemd-boot in my PopOS installation (there is not a real reason why, i like GRUB more and i would like to learn how to work with bootloaders a little bit better).
I think i'm close but i can't manage to make it work, those are the steps i've followed.

- Installing popOS providing a NEW temp efi partition and boot from it (that will be /dev/mydrive/partition5)
- Umount that partition and instead mount in /boot/efi the current EFI 
  partition i'm using also for window (/dev/mydrive/partition2)
- Modified the /etc/fstab to mount at startup partition2 instead of partition5
- Install grub-efi (that include os-prober and grub-efi -amd64)
- grub-install && update-grub, that detect both the current installation of Popos and
  windows, i can also see them inside grub-customizer.

Problem is that as soon as i turn-on the pc with the current config, i'm presented with the grub terminal, if i try to force the boot (grub>boot) i receive an error stating `you need to load the kernel first`.

What im doing wrong? I also tried to wipe partition 5 and uninstall systemd-boot with `uninstall systemd-boot`.

Thanks!

Comment: May be best to see details, use ppa version with your live installer (2nd option) or any working install,  not older Boot-Repair ISO:
Please copy & paste the pastebin link to the Boot-info summary report ( do not post report), the auto fix sometimes can create more issues.
 https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair  If you run grub-customizer, it creates proxy grub files, or its own versions.